# QQ plot for log-logistic and 2 parameter exponential in r

Tags: r, exponential-distribution, qq-plot

Is there any package in R, which help us to plot QQ plot for log logistic distribution and 2 parameter exponential distribution? What methodology can be adopted for the same?